# How are inline handlers processed?

Tags: javascript, inline, handlers

I have the suspicion that inline handlers are `evalled`, but can't find any information on that. Out of curiosity then: does anyone knows how such handlers are processed? For clarity, I mean inline handlers like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomethingReallyCunning()">...</a>
<input type="checkbox" onmouseover="this.checked=!this.checked;this.blur()"/>
```

etc.

Comment: I think this was asked before but I cannot find it. The content of the attributes are taken and a new function with this body and `event` as parameter is created (at least in W3C compatible browsers). Is this what you wanted to know? Or more detailed?

Comment: I coulnd't find it either, not on SO nor using google. If a new funtion is created, I think we can confirm that an eval is taking place then? That's actually all I want to know. If so, it's an argument against using such inline handlers I'd say.

Comment: And what do you exactly mean by `eval` ed? Why would that be a problem? Injection of malicious code? It's of course interpreted, but do you mean ‘when is this code interpreted, at parse time or at run time?’

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: I mean parse time, and the problem would be that everytime such a handler is called, that would spawn a new interpreter ('compiler') - so it's about speed and memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, inline event attributes are processed by creating an anonymous wrapper function like this:

```
element.onclick = new Function("event", onclickAttribute);
// etc.
```

This means that the contents of the attribute are `eval`ed but only when the element is inserted into the DOM (after this the function is in a parsed form in memory, just like other event handlers). This means that it will not consume much more memory and time than event handlers assigned in your own, separate JavaScript code. And even if the code had to be parsed every time the event occurs, it wouldn't make such a big difference that a user will notice it.

However, there's a good reason to stay away from using inline event attributes: keeping presentation and logic separate from each other, which improves readability and maintainability. Another advantage is that using minifiers is less painful, as those function names in your JavaScript files may be changed depending on the minifier's settings and intelligence, but not in your markup (a work around to this issue is to use the square bracket notation when defining those functions in your code (like `window['doSomethingReallyCunning'] = function (…) {…`), so the function name will be kept intact; however, this is of course not a neat solution if there's a much better one available). If you only assign event handlers in your code by directly referencing functions, all instances of that function's name are changed (of course, the same is true for parameters to `setTimeout` and `setInterval`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The separation of structure and logic (or structure and behavior) I knew of, but the minifier argument is also a strong one. Function names may be changed in code anyhow, so if you use third party scripting and refer to functions from that inline, it's the same argument. I haven't used inline handlers for years, but got unsecure about it's mechanisms after some SO question a few days ago.

Comment: @Kooilnc: which one, if I may ask?